# How do you extract rows that match a list of subject ID in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many subject IDs (each subject with repeat observations).

I also have a separate dataframe with just a list of Subject IDs I want to match and extract from the larger dataframe.

How do I write the code in a way that allows me to reference the list of SubjectIDs in a different dataframe?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm fully understanding the question, but here's an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("chicken", "snake"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("monkey", "elephant", "chicken"),
                  useful_data = 1:3)
```

We could subset `df2` to only show rows where `df2$ID` matches an `ID` from `df1$ID`. In R, you can subset a data frame using brackets where you specify `[rows_we_want, cols_we_want]` and leaving one of those blank outputs all rows or all columns, as the case may be.

```
df2[df2$ID %in% df1$ID,]

#       ID useful_data
#3 chicken           3
```